# Having issues trying to plot SPC outlook in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, importerror

My code works perfectly until I go to run this cell

```
panel = MapPanel()

panel.title = 'SPC Day 1 Convective Outlook (Valid 12z Mar 31 2023)'

panel.plots = [geo]

panel.area = [-120, -75, 25, 50]

panel.projection = 'lcc'

panel.layers = ['lakes', 'land', 'ocean', 'states', 'coastline', 'borders']

pc = PanelContainer()

pc.size = (12, 8)

pc.panels = [panel]
pc.show()
```

Then I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name lgeos

These are the packages that I currently have imported:

```
import geopandas
from shapely import geometry
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data
from metpy.plots import MapPanel, PanelContainer, PlotGeometry
```

Any tips or guidance?